# ubuntu crashed after freeing the space using gparted live bootable pen drive

Tags: 16.10

i am user of ubuntu 16.10. I am new to ubuntu, yesterday I free some space of my home partition using gparted live bootable pen drive,but didn't install the windows. I seperate it easily without any error. But when i try to turn on the the ubuntu it is now showing some terminal like screen . It shows a line stating

> systemd-fstab-generator[225]:Failed to create mount unit file /run/systemd/generator/media-cdrom.mount,as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?

And shownig below this:

> You are in emergency mode.

Please help me guys i don't want to lose my data its very important for me

Comment: How exactly did you free up the space? If you deleted something, what did you delete? You stated using a liveusb, you can use that to recover some files from the disk in the meantime.

Comment: i free up the space by draging the partition bar from right to left @KryštofPíštěk

Comment: Did you drag the whole partition, or just a bar which shows how big it is?

Comment: I drag it half of the partition @Kryštof Píštěk